# Can't create a directory using DocumentFile.createDirectory() on Android 7

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard

I have granted permission to write external and removable storages. But I still can't write everywhere on the sd card on Android 7.

```
Intent intent = storageVolume.createAccessIntent(null);
startActivityForResult(intent, 989);
```

;

```
RxPermissions.getInstance(getActivity())
                .request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (!granted) return;
                    showAlternativeDirectoryChooser();//success
                }, throwable -> {
                });
```

Here is the code of folder creation:

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(dir);
DocumentFile test = documentFile.createDirectory("test_folder");
```

test  == null

Comment: What exactly is `dir`? Please edit your question and show your `onActivityResult()` method (for handling case 989) and where `dir` gets populated. Feel free to get rid of the `RxPermissions` stuff, as that has nothing to do with `createAccessIntent()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare how a result have to be handled in the onActivityResult? Because now I do not do anything

Comment: **Any time** you call `startActivityForResult()`, you implement `onActivityResult()` to get the result. That's the point of `startActivityForResult()`. In your case, in `onActivityResult()`, you will be given an `Intent`, and the `Uri` in the `Intent` represents your access to the storage volume. You use that with `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get what you refer to as `documentFile` in your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not a noob). And I can read the docs. But this does not help to gain access anyway. My path to the sd card is correct. That is not an issue

Comment: `My path to the sd card is correct. That is not an issue `. Well it is. And it is nonsense. I suggest you to read the docs. And follow the suggestions you got here. Use onActivityResult.

Comment: @greenapps I have already tested both solutions. Via those tree that I've received in the onActivityResult and via volumes paths. None of them does not seem to work properly. Even more: when I use tree path in another activity to init the DocumentFile it crashes

Comment: Show your code that leads to a crash.

Comment: @greenapps both DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File(path));' and 'DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(DirectoryPicker.this, Uri.parse(path));

Comment: `path` is not a variable delivered by onActivityResult. So your code is wrong. Again we cannot see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot use :**

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(dir);
```

*Becouse its not a SAF valid Uri.*

**If you dont want to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to get an Uri**, you can convert FILE to Uri (SAF) using the following method valid from API19(Android4.4-Kitkat) to API28(Android8-Oreo). The returned Uri's are the same that return the dialog and its valid for API 28 security restrictions (SAF permissions), if you want to access external removable storage outside your application...

```
    /**
 * Ing.N.Nyerges 2019 V2.0
 *
 * Storage Access Framework(SAF) Uri's creator from File (java.IO),
 * for removable external storages
 *
 * @param context Application Context
 * @param file File path + file name
 * @return Uri[]:
 *   uri[0] = SAF TREE Uri
 *   uri[1] = SAF DOCUMENT Uri
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static Uri[] getSafUris (Context context, File file) {

    Uri[] uri = new Uri[2];
    String scheme = "content";
    String authority = "com.android.externalstorage.documents";

    // Separate each element of the File path
    // File format: "/storage/XXXX-XXXX/sub-folder1/sub-folder2..../filename"
    // (XXXX-XXXX is external removable number
    String[] ele = file.getPath().split(File.separator);
    //  ele[0] = not used (empty)
    //  ele[1] = not used (storage name)
    //  ele[2] = storage number
    //  ele[3 to (n-1)] = folders
    //  ele[n] = file name

    // Construct folders strings using SAF format
    StringBuilder folders = new StringBuilder();
    if (ele.length > 4) {
        folders.append(ele[3]);
        for (int i = 4; i < ele.length - 1; ++i) folders.append("%2F").append(ele[i]);
    }

    String common = ele[2] + "%3A" + folders.toString();

    // Construct TREE Uri
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme(scheme);
    builder.authority(authority);
    builder.encodedPath("/tree/" + common);
    uri[0] = builder.build();

    // Construct DOCUMENT Uri
    builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme(scheme);
    builder.authority(authority);
    if (ele.length > 4) common = common + "%2F";
    builder.encodedPath("/document/" + common + file.getName());
    uri[1] = builder.build();

    return uri;
}
```

Then you can call the permissions using something like this:

```
    context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), uri, Intent
            .FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent
            .FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent
            .FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent
            .FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android delivers the Uri you need to use in `onActivityResult`. That Uri is not necessarily related, at all, to the path you're trying to access. You cannot guess it. You have to actually use the Uri you're given.

If you call `DocumentFile.fromFile` or `Uri.parse`, then you are wrong.